# How to get index corresponding to quantile in Polars List?

Tags: python-polars

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'x':[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]]})
```

To get the nth percentile, I can do the following:

```py
list_quantile_30 = pl.element().quantile(0.3)
df.select(pl.col('x').arr.eval(list_quantile_30))
```

But I can't figure out how to get the index corresponding to the percentile? Here is how I would do it using numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
series = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
np.searchsorted(series, np.percentile(series, 30))
```

Is there a way to do this in a Polars way without using apply?

Comment: If your data is sorted, isn't identifying the position of the element at the 30% quantile the same thing as taking the length of the array and multiplying by 0.30, then rounding?

Comment: Yes that's correct in the example but in my own use case I also have nan values which wouldn't work (I am basically using the idx as a column identifier.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your example you could use `pl.arg_where` to search for a condition.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'x':[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]]})

list_quantile_30 = pl.element().quantile(0.3)

df.with_column(pl.col('x').arr.eval(
    pl.arg_where(list_quantile_30 <= pl.element()).first()
).flatten().alias("arg_where"))
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌────────────────┬───────────┐
│ x              ┆ arg_where │
│ ---            ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64]      ┆ u32       │
╞════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ [0, 2, ... 20] ┆ 3         │
└────────────────┴───────────┘
```

This convinces me to add a `pl.search_sorted` in polars as well.